# ScrollView not working in iOS7 with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, ios7

Today I've spend a few hours but still have no answer on very simple (I think it should be so) question: how to make anything scrollable in iOS7 with auto layout feature on.
I added ScrollView into the View (I'm using Storyboard). Then I added multiline Label to this ScrollView. Then I tried all that I could found in Internet but with no luck. Text not scrolling. It's killing me, guys :(((. Help me please maybe with some simple code snippet.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried setting the content size to something larger than the scroll view's frame size?

Comment: Is the multiline label larger than the scroll view? If not, you have to turn on bouncing to get any scrolling happening. If that's not the problem, it would be helpful to NSLog the two views in question for diagnosis.

Comment: @vaskal08, yes! I've tried 1000 x 1000, and no result. I created fresh view for testing, so nothing could impact I think...

Comment: @JesseRusak, yes, label is in 2-3 times bigger then ScrollView.

Comment: bouncing is turned on. when I also turn on Vertical Bouncing I can see springing effect and hidden text, but it is not fixed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you add constraints between ScrollView and Label, ScrollView's content size will adjust automatically and text will scroll:

[image]

Comment: ...also after you setup the last one (the most bottom) constraint to the bottom edge of scrollview, you should set value of this constraint to 0 (if you don't want to have scrollable empty space at the bottom).