# iOS: UIScrollView doesn't scroll down to bottom of its subviews

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which contains more subviews then the screen can display (that's why I am using the scrollview), but the scrollview doesn't allow for the bottom most subviews to scroll into view (they only bounce back, when scrolled down to the bottom, but are unreachable for user interaction)
Any suggestions?

Comment: Change your `scrollview.contentSize` to be vertically bigger.

Comment: Are you using autolayout ? If you do then check my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21456360/507323

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212877/scrollview-not-working-in-ios7-with-autolayout ?

Comment: @Putz1103 - doesn't work

Comment: Please add some relevant code.

Answer (score 5):

I was using AutoLayout with the suggested constraints. Removing a single constraint fixed it, though it was just a lucky guess. Still don't understand why removing that constraint from the myriad of suggested constraint fixed the problem. I only understand now, that when using AutoLayout, UIScrollViews may not work if the constraints are incorrect, or no constraints are applied at all.